findByIdAndUpdate is not updating the document
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectMongo from "@/libs/mongoose";
import User from "@/models/User";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "@/libs/next-auth";
import { Types } from "mongoose";
// This route updates the current session user with the provided information from the body.
export async function PATCH(req) {
  await connectMongo();

  const body = await req.json();

  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

    if (!session || !session.user || !session.user.id) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not authenticated" }, { status: 401 });
    }

    const userId = new Types.ObjectId(session.user.id);
    console.log(body);
    // Find the user by ID and update with provided body data
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      userId,
      {
        firstName: body.firstName,
        lastName: body.lastName,
        phone: body.phone,
        country: body.country,
        lifeStage: body.lifeStage,
        notifications: body.notifications,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    console.log(updatedUser);
    if (!updatedUser) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    return NextResponse.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: e.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

How come the findByIdAndUpdate isnt working? Its not updating anything. I logged the body and it has the correct info. So why isn't it updating?
This is my model:
js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import toJSON from "./plugins/toJSON";

// USER SCHEMA
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    lifeStage: {
      type: String,
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: String,
    },
    notifications: {
      email: {
        type: Array,
      },
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
    },
    // Used in the Stripe webhook to identify the user in Stripe and later create Customer Portal or prefill user credit card details
    customerId: {
      type: String,
      validate(value) {
        return value.includes("cus_");
      },
    },
    // Used in the Stripe webhook. should match a plan in config.js file.
    priceId: {
      type: String,
      validate(value) {
        return value.includes("price_");
      },
    },
    // Used to determine if the user has access to the product—it's turn on/off by the Stripe webhook
    hasAccess: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

// add plugin that converts mongoose to json
userSchema.plugin(toJSON);

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

So what did I do wrong? It doesn't make sense. I looked up everywhere to see why, I researched, I even asked ChatGPT. It makes no sense.
I use NextAuth. Node.JS and Mongoose
